# Help with NHibernate query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I have 2 tables, Plan and Ticket. I want all the records that are in TravelPlan  but not in Ticket.

```
    Template.Criteria.CreateCriteria("Plan")
              .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("UserID",
                                            DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Ticket))
              .SetProjection(Projections.Property("UID"))));
```

The above query doesnt return any records..

Answer (score 1):

I can't guess what SearchTemplate does, but you are applying the projection to the outer criteria instead of the detached one.

Also, the "root" criteria should be for TravelPlan, not Ticket.

In other words:

```
criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<TravelPlan>()
               .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn(
                        "UserId",
                        DetachedCriteria.For<Ticket>()
                            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("UID"))))
```

This assumes TravelPlan has a `UserID` property that is matches the `UID` property in Ticket.